How to run two-way anova + Tukey post-hoc test over multiple columns in dataframe R
I have a dataset where I have 4 groups (wt, ko (Genotype) and (Treatment) a and b) which I want to do two-way anova for (Gene expression ~ Genotype*Treatment) and subsequently a Tukey post-hoc (if anova p<0.05), without having to run it manually for each gene separately and in the end save it all in an Excel file.
The data:
structure(
  list(
    Sample = c(
      "S01", "S02", "S03", "S04", "S05", "S06", 
      "S07", "S08", "S09", "S10", "S11", 
      "S12", "S13", "S14", "S15", "S16", 
      "S17", "S18", "S19", "S20"
    ), 
    Treatment = c(
      "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", 
      "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", 
      "a", "b", "a", "b"
    ), 
    Genotype = c(
      "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "ko", 
      "ko", "ko", "ko", "ko", "ko", "wt", 
      "wt", "wt", "wt", "ko", "ko", "ko", 
      "ko"
    ), 
    Gene_1 = c(
      16.2065526849037, 16.0124531727829, 
      21.436163003663, 13.5607712765957, 
      16.8964727722772, 10.724266513895, 
      18.5570075757576, 17.8408131915351, 
      21.5752835051546, 12.3623776198679, 
      16.057095410628, 12.1751921002158, 
      11.706712962963, 10.3022021943574, 
      14.2375294612795, 13.2317875036131, 
      16.8477678571429, 13.2266017735494, 
      17.3933715374253, 15.1120725400252
    ), 
    Gene_2 = c(
      8.19, 9.835, 17.3859677419355, 11.57, 
      15.1875, 9.85138554216867, 11.2509090909091, 
      6.62424050632911, 9.59178571428571, 
      8.74333333333333, 11.885641025641, 
      6.33636363636364, 18.248152173913, 
      5.18858108108108, 11.6094936708861, 
      14.3825, 20.9, 12.545, 15.1689179104478, 
      9.9339705882353
    ), 
    Gene_3 = c(
      3.84794117647059, 4.37944029850746, 
      3.58586734693878, 4.84867088607595, 
      6.02779411764706, 1.17857142857143, 
      7.53882352941176, 6.54299019607843, 
      1.95732558139535, 4.28607142857143, 
      1.63777777777778, 1.14019230769231, 
      10.5891666666667, 1.17474358974359, 
      3.015, 4.7025, 4.37450704225352, 
      17.1204310344828, 5.66027027027027, 
      4.62239361702128
    ), 
    Gene_4 = c(
      147.034545454545, 17.8463793103448, 
      140.725975609756, 93.4277777777778, 
      180.04238372093, 152.558684210526, 
      228.370135135135, 143.788863636364, 
      180.288333333333, 31.670625, 115.7475, 
      44.4186627906977, 112.962321428571, 
      47.5317567567568, 149.027222222222, 
      79.9246875, 152.92625, 168.775192307692, 
      91.2176086956522, 120.374274193548
    ), 
    Gene_5 = c(
      10.7254545454545, 13.7767883211679, 
      10.2914432989691, 22.1914661654135, 
      12.9418902439024, 15.7779838709677, 
      10.15640625, 14.8137037037037, 15.7697448979592, 
      9.08057339449541, 10.2778164556962, 
      8.17656976744186, 14.4702380952381, 
      11.0587096774194, 10.3093859649123, 
      18.591062992126, 18.065625, 16.7328571428571, 
      10.7228921568627, 10.3396428571429
    ), 
    Gene_6 = c(
      6.94, 7.52, 8.98, 6.98, 12.26, 7.54, 
      9.14, 9.08, 12.22, 5.66, 8.42, 4.62, 
      10.22, 6.26, 11.46, 8.66, 8.88, 8.1, 
      9.18, 13.16
    )
  ), 
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
  row.names = c(NA, - 20L)
)

I tried to adapt a code I've found in this post
for (i in 4:ncol(df)){
  column <- names(df[i])
  anova <- aov(df[,i] ~ Genotype*Treatment, data = df)
  tukey <- TukeyHSD(anova)
    
    print(column)
    print(setNames(tukey, column))
    
}

which gives me the following error

Error in model.frame.default(formula = df[, i] ~ Genotype * Treatment,
:    invalid type (list) for variable 'df[, i]'

Even if I unlist() the variables Genotype & Treatment, the code gives the same error.
If you could help me generate a code that could loop through my dataset, which would give the p-values of the ANOVA, Tukey post hoc AND save it in an excel file I would be very grateful!
